# What's the difference between selectors in CSS and jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I have some questions about selectors (e.g. `:first-child`...).

1. Are jQuery and CSS selectors the same in terms of syntax and usage? If not, what is the difference?
2. It seems the term selector only refers to CSS and jQuery, so does that mean selectors can only be used in CSS and jQuery? If not, in what other languages can we use them?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are practically equal, jQuery could have some extra selectors documented in http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors but most important: you can use for e.g.
$('#foo img') or $('.a, .b, #c') and in your css you can use :checked{...}

Also check this out
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Whenever I see [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com/) link on stack..i really feel like what you have on your profile pic :P

Comment: JQuery allows one to use `:contains` for searching within an element's text. This is not available in css selectors.